Defining \left\right-like commands to be larger than their contents
In short, I would like to define a new pair of commands, say \bigleft and \bigright, which basically have the effect of
\bigleft({some math here}\bigright) = \left({some math here}^\vphantom1\right)
Forcing a slightly larger size for the brackets. I think this would look much better for expressions with lots of nested brackets.
Is it possible to define such commands? From what I've seen, defining new commands with \left and \right is nearly impossible, so I don't know if there's a good way to do this with a new command.

Forcing a slightly larger size for the brackets. I think this would look much worse for expressions with lots of nested brackets.

The usual advice (especially from those who can remember the correct ordering) is to only use \left/\right when necessary, and otherwise manually size the parentheses using \bigl,...,\Biggl.

just set \delimitershortfall and \delimiterfactor to force large values. (but it will not look nice)


It's generally a good idea to avoid \left\right except when really needed it has a bad effect on horizontal space, even if it doesn't stretch the brackets (see \log here) But if you set \delimiterfactor bigger than 1000 the stretch will be bigger than the content: 20% bigger for 1200 used here.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

OK
\[((x+y)+(x-y))=2x \qquad \log(x)\]

OK
\[\bigl((x+y)+(x-y)\bigr)=2x \qquad \log(x)\]

Hmm
\[\left(\left(x+y\right)+\left(x-y\right)\right)=2x  \qquad \log\left(x\right)\]


Hmm
\delimiterfactor=1200
\[\left(\left(x+y\right)+\left(x-y\right)\right)=2x \qquad \log\left(x\right)\]

\end{document}


I once wrote a letter to Don asking about the mathop-mathopen spacing problem and he admitted that it was an oversight, but now it's too late to fix.

@HenriMenke well except in luatex where you can specify the mathclass while stretchng
